# Route params are undefined in layouts/components in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I'm having problems with route params being undefined in components/layouts in Nuxt 3. It seems like a bug but it would be such a critical bug, that I almost don't believe it can be a bug.

Consider the following files:

```
// pages/index.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <NuxtLink to="/test-123">Click me</NuxtLink>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
// pages/test-[id].vue
<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({ layout: "test" });
const route = useRoute();
console.log("page", route.params.id);
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        {{ route.params.id }}
    </div>
</template>
```

```
// layouts/test.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRoute();
console.log("layout", route.params.id);
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <test></test>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
// components/test.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRoute();
console.log("component", route.params.id);
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        {{ route.params.id }}
    </div>
</template>
```

Clicking the link will give the following console output:

```
layout undefined       [test.vue:4:8](http://localhost:3001/_nuxt/layouts/test.vue)
component undefined    [test.vue:4:8](http://localhost:3001/_nuxt/components/test.vue)
page 123               [test-[id].vue:6:8](http://localhost:3001/_nuxt/pages/test-[id].vue)
```

If we navigate from `/` to `/test-123` with a NuxtLink and print `route.params.id` in the layout, component and page, only the page is able to access the id. The layout and component will print undefined. If I reload the page, the component, layout and page all are able to access the route params. So the issue only occurs when navigating from one page to another.

I'm on Nuxt `3.4.2`. Here is a [reproduction](https://github.com/holwech/nuxt-3-bug-repro) of the issue.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I had this problem and I used <NuxtPage/> instead of <RouterView/> in my App.vue file and my problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem accessing the route parameter in the layouts before. I am unsure if this is related to the `NuxtLink` component.

This is my understanding of why it is doing like this. It is because I think the `NuxtLayout` runs first before the `NuxtPage`. The same thing for the component that is inside the `NuxtLayout`. But, if you try to place the `test` component inside the page, it will display the parameter id.

To fix this, use the `middleware`. As stated on the Nuxt documentation, middleware is ideal for extracting code that you want to run before navigating to a particular route.

`~middlware/check-auth.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to) => {
    console.log('Middleware', to.params.id)
})
```

With this, when you try to navigate to `test-[id]` page it will display the parameter id.

If you want to use the displayed parameter id from the `middleware`, you can use the `useState` composable, like this.

`~middlware/check-auth.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to) => {
    console.log('Middleware', to.params.id)
    useState('routeParamId', () => to.params.id)
})
```

You can use that inside the `layout`.

`~layouts/test.vue`

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const paramId = useState('routeParamId')
console.log('ParamId is', paramId.value)
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

In your `test-[id]` page.
`~pages/test-[id].vue`

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({ layout: "test", middleware: 'check-route' });
const route = useRoute();
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        {{ route.params.id }}
    </div>
</template>
```

Tested and it works.

Comment: This seems to do the trick! I have opened a [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/20471) on Github related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a "shortcut" here: ivan119 found a different solution that has been working for me, as seen in his comment on the Github issue OP created: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/20471#issuecomment-1785954699

> I lost much time until i found solution, please try
>
> ```
> const route = useRouter().currentRoute.value
> const id = route.params.id
> ```
>
> for some reason "useRoute().params.id" is cached